# How to get attribute value in textbox when an item is selected in drop down box?

Tags: javascript, html

NOTE: This question may look duplicate but I haven't found what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to get an attribute value from the selected dropdown item, and write it into a text box when the dropdown is changed/updated.

HTML code:

```
<select id="dropdown" onchange="ChooseContact()">
    <option value='1' cal='One'>1</option>
    <option value='2' cal='Two'>2</option></select>

<input id="abc" type="text">
```

Javascript code:

```
function ChooseContact() {

    var y=document.getElementById("dropdown").options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute("cal");
    document.getElementById("abc").value = y;
}
```

Check live here https://jsfiddle.net/KEY9y/1095/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in browser dev tools console you will see the error `select is undefined`

Then look in the function can see you are using it but it has never been declared

Try

```
function ChooseContact() {
    var select = document.getElementById("dropdown"); // declare "select" 
    var y = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute("cal");
    document.getElementById("abc").value = y;
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bwqegha4/)**</kbd>